# Type Checking in Compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, semantics, typechecking

Is it possible to type check an expression , say x+y , in a language where variables are not declared before use ? Can someone please explain with an example. Thanks in advance .

Comment: You can't do type-checking without that every term in your expression has a type. Is that language dynamic-typed? if so, when the variable gets a new value (for example, with the assignment `=`) operator you need to deduce the type from that value and store somewhere in your AST. Like does PHP language, for example.

Comment: for example, `x = 2; y = 3.5;` you must deduce from constant value `2` that php has INTEGER type and from `3.5`  constant that  `y` has FLOAT type

Comment: But before type-checking I suggest you to do type-promotion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion

Comment: Some language support [Type Inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference); so "variables declared with a specific type", are not required; but "expressions resolvable to a type [or class/restriction of]", is required for any relevant compile-time type checking. Exactly *how* the expressions can be resolved, and what restrictions are enforced, depends heavily on the design of the language.

Answer (score 2):

The main effect of not having variable declarations with regards to type checking would be that your variables don't have explicitly declared types. So your question can be reduced to whether it is possible to type check expressions in languages with no or optional type signatures. The answer to that is yes since there are statically typed languages where type signatures are optional and the types are simply inferred.

An example of this would be Haskell:

```
f x y = x + y
```

Here `f` gets the type `Num a => a -> a -> a`, which means that it takes two numbers of the same type and returns another number of that type. This type is automatically inferred by the compiler if you don't provide it explicitly.